# Are there proof assistants for multi-valued logics?

Tags: many-valued, fuzzy

There are several three-valued logics (like those used in OCL or VDM), four-valued logics (e.g. used for paraconsistency) and real-valued logics (e.g. fuzzy logics with Gödel's or Łukasiewicz's connectives). Are there any proof assistants for these, either directly or via some encodings in some two-valued logic?

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to tackle the non-classical propositional logic case.

Any proof assistant that is capable of proving things in classical first-order logic can be used to analyze a propositional logic by using the following translation. In so doing, we are using the [matrix semantics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-algebraic-propositional/#LogiMatr).

Let $D$ be a one-place predicate that returns true if and only if its argument has a designated truth value. I also insist that for every $n$-ary connective (such as $\cdot$), I have an $n$-ary function (let's say $A$). I'll use $\land, \lor, \lnot$ as classical connectives exclusively.

The inference rule $\frac{A \;\;\text{and}\;\; B}{A \cdot B}$ corresponds to $\forall a, b \mathop. D(a) \land D(b) \to D(A(a, b)) $.

In order to analyze a system like [Belnap's four-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-valued_logic#Belnap), you can introduce another predicate $F$ for the falsity conditions. Within classical FOL, $F$ and $D$ do not have a relationship with each other.